# Powershell: Foreach not working?

Tags: powershell, foreach

So I have an issue with my foreach loop, and I cant figure out what I am doing wrong.

The following is an example of my code:

```
 $objectarray ##( So this variable contains a list of lists ie name + address) ##

 Foreach ($object in $objectarray.name){


$objectid = $objectarray.Where({$_.name -eq "$object"}).id
$objectaddress = $objectarray.Where({$_.name -eq "$object"}).address

$objectprint = "$objectid" + ": " + "$objectaddress"

$objectprint
return 0

}
```

Now the problem is **$objectarray** has multiple lists inside it each with its name, id, address etc

But it ONLY prints the FIRST one, and I get ONLY the first 0 as return...despite the fact there are many of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its because you are returning 0 inside your for loop. Should put that outside the loop.

```
Foreach ($object in $objectarray.name){

    $objectid = $objectarray.Where({$_.name -eq "$object"}).id
    $objectaddress = $objectarray.Where({$_.name -eq "$object"}).address

    $objectprint = "$objectid" + ": " + "$objectaddress"

    $objectprint
}
return 0
```

Comment: Nope, doesnt work, Normally it doesnt make a difference either. Also every Object value is filled with data, none are empty or null, which is the reason why this is so baffling

Comment: you are returning 0

Comment: @A.Zia Sorry Ive updated the answer ( I believe this is the solution )

Comment: It captures the first entry's output which will be like: 100: Abc123 ... and a 0 as the next line (which is required to the other system i am feeding it to) ... but beyond the first entry no other output

Comment: Yeah but that return jumps you out of whatever function you are in, stopping the for loop.

Comment: AAH I see... Thanks.. I guess I'll just echo a "0" as the next line ... Thank you very much

Answer (score 5):

You're parsing through your object in a weird way.  Why don't you use the pipeline to make this a little easier on yourself?

```
$ObjectArray | % { "$($_.id): $($_.address)"; 0 }
```

Everything will be put onto the success/output pipeline this way and can be captured (for example, if you put `$var =` before the expression)

Comment: because the ACTUAL $objectarray being parsed is MASSIVE with many many things to parse through.... And pipeline have memory optimization issues...Thank you very much for your recommendation  though

Comment: Instead of `$ObjectArray | %` you can just use `ForEach ($o in $ObjectArray)` then.